# Updated to android studio 3.0.1, now JDBC .jar dependency isn't working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdbc, dependencies

I updated from Android Studio 2.2.3 to 3.0.1. Now my .jar dependencies are broken somehow.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.DataAccessObjects.DataAccessObject.openConnection(DataAccessObject.java:56)
    at com.DataAccessObjects.DataAccessObject.updateDb(DataAccessObject.java:35)
    at com.DataAccessObjects.AuthTokenDao.createTable(AuthTokenDao.java:45)
    at com.Services.Service.newDaosAtDb(Service.java:45)
    at com.Services.ClearService.<init>(ClearService.java:19)
    at com.Handlers.ClearHandler.<init>(ClearHandler.java:28)
    at com.Server.run(Server.java:37)
    at com.Server.main(Server.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.DataAccessObjects.DataAccessObject.updateDb(DataAccessObject.java:37)
    at com.DataAccessObjects.AuthTokenDao.createTable(AuthTokenDao.java:45)
    at com.Services.Service.newDaosAtDb(Service.java:45)
    at com.Services.ClearService.<init>(ClearService.java:19)
    at com.Handlers.ClearHandler.<init>(ClearHandler.java:28)
    at com.Server.run(Server.java:37)
    at com.Server.main(Server.java:26)
```

Here are my dependencies in the module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation files('libs/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar')
}
```

It deals properly with junit and gson, because without them it complains. But whether or not I include the jdbc .jar, it reacts with the same error message.

EDIT1: I know that somehow it was the update that broke this. I have a computer with 2.2.3 installed, running code that as far as I'm aware is the same, with the exact same .jar file, and it doesn't have any problems. An interesting detail is that while 3.0.1 says "implementation files(...)", 2.2.3 says "compile files(...)"

EDIT2: Still pretty flabbergasted over here. I can instantiate an org.sqlite.JDBC object, and Android Studio recognizes that it's a valid class, but as soon as I call Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"), suddenly it's not a valid class...

```
public void openConnection()throws SQLException{
    try {
        assert connection == null;
        assert dbName.length()>0;
        org.sqlite.JDBC hi = null; //valid code
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); //ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new project and moved all my code into it, and now it's working.

If you want my advice, never update Android Studio when you're working under tight time constraints. This took me all day.